# Where is Kubernetes in Docker (KIND) mapping its Volume Mounts on windwos 10

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kind

Im following the instructions here to install an Elastic Search Cluster on KIND (Kubernetes in Docker). https://www.elastic.co/blog/alpha-helm-charts-for-elasticsearch-kibana-and-cncf-membership

This is running in a 4 node cluster on Docker on Windows 10. Im running into a problem similar to whats reported here: https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/137

Im trying to figure out where the mounts are so I can CHOWN that directory. Where is this mapped on the local machine?

Im not running WSL2 yet

Comment: Could you describe your issue in more detail? Which directory are you looking for? Is it the same as in github issue linked? Please include the error in your question.

Comment: its the same error in the Github link. The solution in the issue is to CHOWN the folder. the question is where is this folder

Comment: Did you try to modify values.yaml file as shown in example for kubernetes-kind? https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/ce50fd1c634d8a814cef2bbc300e0fe5330ad3f8/elasticsearch/examples/kubernetes-kind/values.yaml

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the owner of `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes` directory you have to create an `initContainer` that will change the permissions.

You can do it by fetching elasticsearch chart:

```
helm fetch --untar elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch
```

Then change `values.yaml` and add following lines:

```
antiAffinity: "soft"

# Shrink default JVM heap.
esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

# Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "512M"

# Request smaller persistent volumes.
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "hostpath"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
extraInitContainers: |
  - name: create
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['mkdir', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/']  
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      name: elasticsearch-master
  - name: file-permissions
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['chown', '-R', '1000:1000', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/']
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      name: elasticsearch-master
```

It changes the cpu and memory requests and limits for the pods and starts `initContainer` with `chown', '-R', '1000:1000', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/'` command that changes the permission of the directory.